# how to write a test class for trigger for sending mail ?plz help me out!

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger LeaveUpdatetrigger on Leave__c (after update,before delete) {

    if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate){
        for(Leave__c lv : trigger.new){
            Leave__c lev = [Select Name,EmployeeName__r.Name from Leave__c where EmployeeName__c =:lv.EmployeeName__c limit 1];
            EmailTemplate et = [SELECT Id,Subject,HtmlValue, Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName =:'Update_to_Hr_on_Leave_modification'];
             system.debug('--EmailTemplate--'+et);
            String body = et.HtmlValue;
            body = body.replace('{!Leave__c.EmployeeName__c}',lev.EmployeeName__r.Name);
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.toAddresses = new String[] { 'saudsyed20@gmail.com' };
                mail.setSubject(et.subject);
            mail.setHtmlBody(body);

            mail.setplainTextBody(et.body);
            // mail.setTargetObjectIds(lv.id);
            mail.setTemplateId('00X2v000001H9oK'); //Id of the Email Template
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
        }
    }
     if(Trigger.isBefore || trigger.isdelete){
        for(Leave__c lv : trigger.old)
        {
            Leave__c lev = [Select Name,EmployeeName__r.Name from Leave__c where EmployeeName__c =:lv.EmployeeName__c limit 1];

            EmailTemplate et = [SELECT Id,Subject,HtmlValue, Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName =:'Update_to_HR_on_Leave_deletion'];
            //system.debug('--EmailTemplate--'+et);
            String body1 = 'TEST';
            String body =et.HtmlValue;
            body = body.replace('{!Leave__c.EmployeeName__c}',lev.EmployeeName__r.Name);
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.toAddresses = new String[] { 'saudsyed20@gmail.com' };
                mail.setSubject(et.subject);
            mail.setHtmlBody(body);
            mail.setplainTextBody(et.body);
          mail.setTemplateId('00X2v000001H9oe');//Id of the Email Template
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
        }                   
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create an object of `LeaveUpdatetrigger` then update the object in the test class. The trigger will be fired.

Answer (score 0):

Fields need to be assigned, whichever trigger you use, 
you can write class like this or also you can look there:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_triggers

OR

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_code_coverage_intro.htm

FOR EXAMPLE:

```
@isTest
public class ProcessSurveyTestClass {

    Static testmethod void MyTest(){
        ProcessSurvey__c Pss = new ProcessSurvey__c();
    Pss.CariKodu__c = 'MSO2455';
    Pss.Email__c = 'blabla@blabla.com';
    insert Pss;        
    }
}
```